# How should disabled <div> act?

Tags: html, dom, input

I noticed the following bug when using `$(selector).children().attr("disabled", "disabled")` where the children happened to contain a `<div>`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZuqw/)

```
<div disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="RAGE" />
</div>
```

Basic testing says FF4/Chrome enable the field. IE9 disables the field.

What is the expected behaviour?

Same for any other non form element (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`<div>` elements do not have a `disabled` attribute according to the HTML specification. The expected behavior is to prevent your markup from validating correctly.

However, the new HTML5 specification allows for `<fieldset>` to have a `disabled` attribute, which disables any nested input fields. It's not widely supported yet though, so you won't be able to rely on this feature for a while.

Comment: Not supported in latest Chrome as of today.

Answer (score 11):

There is no `disabled` [attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) for the `div` element. So it should have no effect.

Comment: When given garbage input, the output is garbage? I wouldn't bother. Write valid HTML instead.

Comment: Only if you file it at http://www.mozilla.com/products/download.html?product=firefox-4.0.1. ;)

Comment: I do write valid HTML. The issue came from a `$(selector).children().attr("disabled", "disabled")` which happened to set a div to disabled.

Comment: If your selector returns a div and you try to set the "disabled" attribute on it then you are writing invalid HTML. Don't quibble with good answers.

Comment: The document might be valid HTML, but then you manipulate the DOM into a state where it cannot be serialised into valid HTML.