# jQuery selector ':not()' or method '.not()' behavior in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

The following snippet was tested with chrome 23, firefox 3.5 and IE9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
      <title>test</title>
      <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
      <script>
          $(function() {
              $('#id1 *').not('.c1 *').attr('disabled', true);
          });
      </script>
</head><body>
      <div id="id1">
            <div class="c1">
                <input type=radio>td1</input>
            </div>
            <div class="c2">
                <input type=radio>td2</input>
            </div>
      </div>
</body></html>
```

Only td2 should be disabled, however the usual suspect (IE9) disables td1 AND td2.
How would you get around this problem ?

**Answer**
Actually the problem was not due to the jquery selector but to the fact that when a  element gets attribute 'disabled' in IE9, all  sub-elements are disabled. However this does not happen in Chrome and FF (at least for the versions above).
More information here:  [How should disabled 'div' act?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6307586/400925)

Comment: Have you tried using `input` instead of `*`?

Comment: You are filtering incorrectly, that is not an IE9 issue.

Comment: pimvdb: thanks for the comment: the original selector `$('#id1 *').not('.c1 *')` actually works in all 3 browsers with jquery 1.8.3,  
but Hunter's version `$('#id1 :not(.c1) *')` is more accurate and works in all 3 browsers with jquery 1.7.2 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this selector instead:

```
$('#id1 :not(.c1) input').attr('disabled', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QTG7S/

---

What you wrote should probably be re-written like this:

```
$('#id1 *').not('.c1').find("*").attr('disabled', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QTG7S/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#id1 div').each(function (){
    $(this).children('input').attr('disabled', !$(this).hasClass("c1"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hJTzW/4/

Comment: Could you tell me what difference it does?

Comment: It checks whether `c1` is the only class, and sets and resets. Also, better to use a negated `if`.

Comment: within your `each` you could write `$(this).find("*").attr('disabled', !$(this).hasClass("c1"))`

Comment: Alright, I got your point. Thank you @hunter, I had forgotten the `hasClass` method.

Comment: Almost, make sure you are selecting the `input` within the `.c1` `div` and not the `.c1` `div` itself when you're disabling.

Answer (score 1):

IE is probably doing the right thing:

- `$('#id1 *')` selects all tags inside `#id1` which gives you two div and two input tags
- `.not('.c1 *')` removes the input tag inside `.c1` from the above list, you end up with three elements: two divs and one input
- You apply `disabled=disabled` on the result. In IE, the `<div disabled=disabled>...</div>` disables the div tag and everything inside it.

I believe you can achieve the desired result like this:

```
$('#id1 div:not(.c1) :radio').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Resulting HTML: `<div id="id1">
            <div class="c1" disabled="disabled">
                <input type="radio">td1
            </div>
            <div class="c2" disabled="disabled">
                <input disabled="disabled" type="radio">td2
            </div>
      </div>`