# Enable/Disable using Radio is not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to disable/enable dropdown box based on user selection of radio buttons. I have the following JSFiddle: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QekRS/) which works fine on it's own.

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
    var r_id = $("input[@name=sc]:checked").attr('id');
    alert(r_id);

    if (r_id == "bName") {
        //enable By Name drop down
        $(".dName").prop('disabled', false);
        //disable By Specialty drop down
        $(".dSpecialty").prop('disabled', true);
    }
    if (r_id == "bSpecialty") {
        //enable By Specialty drop down
        $(".dSpecialty").prop('disabled', false);
        //disable By Name drop down
        $(".dName").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

The same exact code in the following page is not working: [**Website Demo**](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/chosen/example.jquery.html)

Comment: Wow. I don't even know how that works. `@` isn't even available as a selector in jQuery 1.3+, it's been removed for a looooooong time. remove the `@`, it's unnecessary.

Comment: Done. Thanks. Everything else works except the disabled/enabled of the drop down box.

Comment: try `$(".dName").removeAttr('disabled');` Instead `$(".dSpecialty").prop('disabled', false);`

Comment: what is the opposite of removeAttr('disabled'); (Updated the page but still same issue)

Comment: Your HTML on your website demo has a ton of validation errors, not sure if that would cause the issue.

Comment: I commented out every code except the enable/disable option but it's still not working

Comment: Is that just your JS file? I'm talking about the example.jquery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code on my local XAMPP server. It appears the the issue is coming from the chosen.jquery.js file. If I remove this script from your example.jquery.html you get the intended behavior.

What's happening is that you start out with a `<select>` tag with all the options which your JS works fine for. However this chosen.jquery.js creates a `<div>` block in place of this `<select>` tag. The 'disabled' property no longer applies to this newly built `<div>` block.

Reference:
[How should disabled <div> act?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307586/how-should-disabled-div-act)

This chosen.jquery.js file looks like some third party custom drop down box. Not sure if the functionality is there already to disable this, you probably need to check the API. If not you need to create a custom CSS class for this div to make it appear faded.

Comment: I wrestled with the codes for hours with enabling and disabling. After a lot of research and experiments, I went ahead with a different solution. Will post link soon :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think a point specifies a class name, and

```
class="chzn-select dSpecialty" name="dSpecialty"
```

has another name to it... You could try changing that

Answer (score 1):

Can you simplify with:

```
$('input[type=radio].searchCriteria').click(function () {
    $('.chzn-select').prop('disabled', true);//disable all
    $(this).next('.chzn-select').prop('disabled', false);//enable sibling
});
```

MIGHT be better: use the change handler (jQuery newer versions):

```
$('input[type=radio].searchCriteria').on('change',function () {
    $('.chzn-select').prop('disabled', true);//disable all
    $(this).next('.chzn-select').prop('disabled', false);//enable sibling
});
```

Prior versions of jQuery without '.on' (direct)

```
$('input[type=radio].searchCriteria').change(function () {
    $('.chzn-select').prop('disabled', true);//disable all
    $(this).next('.chzn-select').prop('disabled', false);//enable sibling
});
```

OR if you need for dynamic elements (use wrapper div etc. not "document" if possible)

```
$(document).delegate('input[type=radio].searchCriteria','change',function () {
    $('.chzn-select').prop('disabled', true);//disable all
    $(this).next('.chzn-select').prop('disabled', false);//enable sibling
});
```

Comment: Are you recommending the second option?

Comment: Yes, should work better to use change than click - - what if you click same element, no need to do anything.

Comment: Now it tells me, "$('input[type=radio].searchCriteria').on('change',function () {" Object doesn't support this property of method.

Answer (score 0):

type, name, id and class atributes must be wrapped with double quotes. Updated code:
 [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QekRS/1/)

```
<input type="radio" name="sc" id="bName" class="searchCriteria checked" />
```

Update

In this part of the code

```
if (r_id == "bSpecialty") {
            //enable By Specialty drop down
            $(".dSpecialty").prop('disabled', false);
            //disable By Name drop down
            $(".dName").prop('disabled', true);
    }
```

Replace it for

```
  if (r_id == "bSpecialty") {
                //enable By Specialty drop down
                $(".dSpecialty").removeAttr('disabled');
                //disable By Name drop down
                $(".dName").Attr('disabled', true);
        }
```

And tell me want happen

Comment: class=searchCriteria and it's CHECKED by default. I did double quote everything but did not work :(

Comment: did you open the link i posted? there is the updated code and it worked

Comment: MY JS fiddle at the beginning is what i did and it worked fine but for some reason it's not working on the Website Demo page :/

Comment: Did you include your jquery file? open the console and check if there is an error.

Comment: Yes, i checked console and there are no errors reported :/ If you look at this: http://www.interfaithmedical.com/chosen/example.jquery.html you will see that for some reason it doesnt take off the DISABLED feature.

Comment: I will update the code for both NAME and SPECIALTY... and will update you. Thanks